# Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@ID_PLA" при извлечении данных из курсора

Tags: sql, sql-server

Имеется следующий код:

```
DECLARE @ID_PLA INT
SET @ID_PLA = 0

DECLARE Zakaz_cursor1 CURSOR
FOR SELECT ID_PLACEMENT FROM Zakaz


OPEN Zakaz_cursor1

FETCH NEXT FROM Zakaz_cursor1 INTO @ID_PLA

PRINT @ID_PLA
```

Необходимо, чтобы данный код создавал курсор, который будет содержать `ID_PLACEMENT`. После из этого курсора извлекается первая строка и добавляется переменная, которая потом выводится. Однако при выполнении команды

```
FETCH NEXT FROM Zakaz_cursor1 INTO @ID_PLA
```

выдает ошибку:

`Необходимо объявить скалярную переменную "@ID_PLA"`

В чем проблема? Я ж переменную объявляю:

```
DECLARE @ID_PLA INT
```

Comment: Весь код должен работать, отдельная команда и не должна работать. А зачем здесь вообще курсор, почему не выбрать сразу `TOP (1) ID_PLACEMENT` в переменную?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin просто как пример работы с курсором рассматриваю